# Eclipse m2e, workspace resolution and JBoss deployment issues

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss

I'm using eclipse to work on a number of Maven projects. In particular one is a WAR project (let's call it `project-a`) which has a dependency on a JAR project (let's call it `project-b`).

When I try to deploy to JBoss 7.1 the WAR project, the deployiment will fail, with JBoss complaining about `project-b-x.x.x.SNAPSHOT.jar` being empty zip file.

In fact if I open the generated war with an archiver, I can see that `project-b-x.x.x.SNAPSHOT.jar` is not beign embedded as a zip file, but a folder.

The issue is only present in this scenario.

When I create the the WAR from command line, from Eclipse with `project-b` closed or workspace resolution disabled, the WAR will contain a zip as expected.

If I deploy the WAR from Eclipse, with the JAR project closed, or workspace resolution disabled, the deployment will succeed.

Deployments to a Glassfish server will work, even in the former case.

I'm not even sure which one to blame, JBoss or Eclipse, but I'll be happy with any solution that either tells m2eclipse to always bundle the zip, or JBoss to be less picky about what I'm deploying on it.

Edit: I'm using the following versions of the software

Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0 (Not sure about which version of Eclipse it uses)
m2e 1.3.1.20130219
JBoss 7.1.1.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of JBoss 7.1.1:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4704

The issue has been resolved in version 7.1.3, which is not available as a download in binary form, so I'll have to either compile it by myself, or disable workspace integration when working with WARs